# A good approach to know existence of a record in a table

Tags: python, django

I have next model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In views.py

-When I try this one:

```
 if People.objects.get(id=my_id):
        o=People.objects.get(id=my_id)
        oh=o.name
    else:
        send_notification_to_add_that_id(my_id)
```

I get this:

```
People query matching does not exist.
```

What I want is that Query the `my_id` in my `People` table, if there is a match with that record get the `id`, else trigger the `send_notification_to_add_that_id` method.
When first "if conditions" does not have such a record, i am getting above error. How to by pass this issue? What is the good approach to know existence of a record in a table ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [throwing an exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get):

> If there are no results that match the query, get() will raise a DoesNotExist exception.

so you need to handle it:

```
try:
    People.objects.get(id=my_id)
except People.DoesNotExist:
    send_notification_to_add_that_id(my_id)
```

alternativly you could do

```
people = People.objects.filter(id=my_id)
if people.exists():
    person = people[0]
```

as `filter` doesn't raise an exception if there are no results - it simply returns an empty `QuerySet` but this runs the risk of returning more then one object, so it doesn't make as much sense as the first example.

As an aside, it makes more sense to call your model `Person` instead of `People` as that is what is being represented by your model or in the case of the DB, each row in your table.

Comment: Thanks, I have one more thing that When I call the 'send_notification_to_add_that_id(my_id)' Does it have to be return something?

Comment: That method is responsible for inserting 'id' to my table. It is possible that method may face an error, so in this case, do I need to return something? something like success message ??

Comment: A table outside your django application? If not, why aren't you just using the ORM?

Comment: No, it is inside of my application, What is ORM?

Comment: You need to have a read through the django docs. [Here is a good document about queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/). The ORM is the layer of abstraction (in the form of an API) that django provides to make querying easier. You are using the ORM when you write `People.objects.get()`

Comment: I see, I already use ORM inside my method instead row sql query, such as 'p=People(id=my_id, name='foo', lastname='bar') p.save()'. The thing is that do I need to return a message after saving the new data to the table?